# Cannot bind argument at index 3 because the index is out of range. The statement has 1 parameters

Tags: android, android-cursor

I got the error in below code. What's the root cause?

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                TaskEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_STATUS + "=?",
                new String[]{TaskStatus.NEW.name(), TaskStatus.FINISHED.name(), TaskStatus.DELETED.name()},
                null
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the root cause?

your where clause/string `TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_STATUS + "=?",` has only one "placeholder", `=?`, but you are providing three different pieces of information for the substitution,

`new String[]{TaskStatus.NEW.name(), TaskStatus.FINISHED.name(), TaskStatus.DELETED.name()}`

the number of `?` has to match the size of the `String`'s array. So in your case it should be only one. As pointed out by `@Gabe`, you can either use `IN` or `OR` if you want to fetch the columns with one of those values

Comment: @JiYa if you want to see if the value is any of the three values do "TaskEntry.COLUMN_TASK_STATUS IN (value1, value2, value3)"

Comment: Thanks, @Gabe, and Blackbelt